# CollapsingToolbarLayout when image is white

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my app, I implemented a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` containing a Facebook picture and text, like the image below:

I'm having a problem when the picture contains too much white, the `Toolbar` icons stays invisible.

[image]

I'd like to do like Google Play Store (image below), I saw that I needed to activate `windowTranslucentStatus` on style, but this applies only to status bar, I'd like to extend this effect to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, but I couldn't make it work.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this view as a first element of your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to make something similar:

```
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:src="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />
```

Code for the drawable `toolbar_shadow`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted! I just added some transparency to the start color (#80000000). Thanks